# Django prepopulation + appending fixed string

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Consider the following (simplified) Django model:

```
Noun(models.Model):
    noun = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    plural = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I want to be able to enter, say, 'cat' in the noun field and have the plural field be automatically populated with 'cats'.  That is, I want to define a string to be appended to the end of a prepopulated field.  Is this possible?

I know I can prepopulate it with 'cat' with the appropriate setting in admin.py, but this is not enough.  Of course, it is also important that I be able to edit the entry after prepopulation (in case of irregular words).  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: `plural = str(noun) + 's'`?  Sorry if I'm off, django is not my forte

Answer (score 2):

Make the plural blank=True and do something like this in your save():

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.plural:
        self.plural = self.noun + 's'
    super(Noun, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would actually do this in javascript client side so the data entry person can correct if it is incorrect.

Comment: That is great, thanks!  Just one thing: I had to replace 'self.noun' with 'str(self.noun)' to prevent a type error.  Perhaps because my noun is actually a foreign key pointing to a list of words?

Comment: Ouch.  str(self.noun) will be replaced by the results of __unicode__ or __str__ method called on the object self.noun.  Sounds like this may be more complex an issue that this simple answer will cover.